# Debian installer does not create desktop/launcher link

Tags: software-center, application-development, icons, symbolic-link

I have a Qt application that I want to deploy as a deb package. I have been reading so many sources, all slightly different - most of what I did follows this [How To: preparing an application for submission to the Ubuntu Software Centre](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-prepare-a-compiled-application-for-ubuntu-software-center/)

My files are an executable MainProject, a few dependent libraries, Qt libraries and a number of other system libraries that I have to include for deploying on a different system with nothing installed. I created an sh file that sets the library path, then executes the program - so the sh file will have to be launched every time I guess.

I must create a folder structure in `/usr/share/MyCompanyFolder/` and associate the executable with an icon. (The spaces and special characters in the path are an unfortunate requirement; the uppercase names also... the program was ported from windows).

/usr/share/My Company's Folder/MainProject/content

I created a package... and it seems to work, installs in the correct location, and surprisingly the program even works after that.

**The Problem: The "MainProject.desktop" seems to have no effect** - I was hoping to see a link looking like the ico file, placed on the launcher (maybe desktop ? why is it called .desktop ?)...

Setup:

```
~/working_directory
   mainproject-1.0
      mainproject_1
         content
         MainProject
         MainProject.sh
      MainProject.ico
      MainProject.desktop
   mainproject-1.0.tar.gz
```

MainProject.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MainProject
Icon=MyCompanyFolder/MainProject.ico 
Type=Application
Categories=Text;
Exec=bash /usr/share/MyCompanyFolder/MainProject/MainProject.sh
Version=1.0
Comment=MainProject is awesome.
Path=/usr/share/MyCompanyFolder/MainProject/
Terminal=false
```

Inside `mainproject-1.0` I ran

```
dh_make --copyright gpl -f ../mainproject-1.0.tar.gz
```

Select s, press enter... Then I modified the files in the debian folder created. Ran

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -my@email.com
```

Result: It works, creates installer, installer works...

- The MainProject.desktop file is in /usr/share/applications (but it
  is a blank thing, with no icon)
- The icon is added in /usr/share/icons/MyCompanyFolder - but... useless
- There is nothing in the launcher or desktop
- MainProject.desktop does launch the application.

What is missing ? From what I read, placing the *.desktop item in the applications folder would be enough to create a launcher item... And how does the icon get associated with it ?

Comment: Your main link is dead. Here is a new one from web archive https://web.archive.org/web/20141210051522/http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-prepare-a-compiled-application-for-ubuntu-software-center/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that all icons used for shortcuts are png files not ico...

I created a png for my icon and it magically worked.

This fixed both the association with the launcher and the fact that the launcher did not work